# Get actual tile load error with OpenLayers 4.6.4

Tags: openlayers-3

I am using the `tileloaderror` event on an `ol.source.Tile` to catch errors that occur during loading of the tile. Is there any built-in way to get the actual error from the HTTP request that originated from the tile load?

Thanks

Comment: if `built-in` means on javascript itself, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630650/detect-404-error-on-page-load

Comment: Thanks for your reply @ChaseChoi. To be more clear, I am looking for a built-in function in the context of OpenLayers, if there is any