# How to handle 404 image url on tinyMCE Javascript

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

[Tiny MCE Pop Up for Uploads](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzHtz.png)

So, I want to check if the pasted url is not 404. Using Javascript. Is there an overrideable function like images_upload_handler?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [detect 404 error on page load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26630650/detect-404-error-on-page-load)

Comment: Isn't that too broad?

Comment: What do you mean ? I think not because you ask to check for all URL, and the linked question check it. After, you just have to well implement this in your form

Comment: xD So, what do you mean with "too broad" ? Why it doesn't correspond to your question

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.